# WCF mixing XML and JSON in one object

Tags: c#, json, xml, wcf, datacontract

I have an object that is sent via WCF using DataContracts and XML.

Would it be possible to receive an JSON encoded element inside this XML object only by using DataContract and related attributes?

Something like

```
<xmlroot>
    <someElement>1</someElement>
    <cuckooJson>{"foo" : "bar" }</cuckooJson>
</xmlroot>
```

I know this is quite ugly and assume the answer is no by I wanted to ask anyway.

Comment: Of course you can. Make the property a string property and call your own JSON serializer on the object you want to send as JSON, assigning the resulting string to the property. No, you can't do it with attributes only.

Comment: This is what I suspected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CodeCaster commented, there seems to be no solution to achieve this via DataContract attributes without using an extra JSON serializer.